# DB -connection with the MySQL driver/API OurSQL for Python?

Tags: python, mysql

OurSQL is the MySQL driver for Python, more [here](http://packages.python.org/oursql/tutorial.html). I fail with the connection, I doubt the problem to be with port or host -- more details [here](http://pastie.org/3923135) about environment vars, I am working with Ubuntu.

```
$ cat t.py 
import oursql
conn=oursql.connect(db='test', user='root', passwd='hello')
#, port=3306)
#, host='127.0.0.1')
conn=oursql.connect(db='test')
curs = conn.cursor(oursql.DictCursor)
curs = conn.cursor(try_plain_query=False)
a=curs.execute('SELECT * from test.pic')

print(a)
$ cat test.sql 
select * from test.pic;

$ python t.py |wc
      1       1       5    
$ mysql test < test.sql |wc
      9      78     610

WHY DIFFERENT LENGTHS??

THIS LINE WRONG (above)????
conn=oursql.connect(db='test', user='root', passwd='hello')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply print the result of `curs.execute(...)` in this way. You're supposed to use the [`fetchone(...)`](http://packages.python.org/oursql/api.html#oursql.Cursor.fetchone) or [`fetchmany(...)`](http://packages.python.org/oursql/api.html#oursql.Cursor.fetchmany) or [`fetchall(...)`](http://packages.python.org/oursql/api.html#oursql.Cursor.fetchall) methods of the cursor object to retrieve its results.

Also, as the [API documentation](http://packages.python.org/oursql/api.html#cursor-classes) points out, iterating over the cursor is equivalent to repeatedly calling `fetchone()`. So, your script could end with something like:

```
curs.execute('SELECT * from test.pic')

for row in curs:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you, got it working -- nice `a=curs.fetchall(); print(a)`, +1.